# HTML5 Javascript return value from Async function

Tags: javascript, html

How can I get the return customers to actually return a customers array from this function?  I mean in another language I would use `Thread.SignalOne` or an `Async callback`.  How can I do this in JS?

```
 var getAllFiles = function() {
 var customers = [];
 var objectStore = dbGlobals.db.transaction("files").objectStore("files");

 objectStore.openCursor().onsuccess = function(event) {
  var cursor = event.target.result;
  if (cursor) {
      if(cursor.key.indexOf(currentFolder) != -1)  {
        customers.push(cursor.value);
      }
      cursor.continue();      
  }
  else {
//  alert("Got all customers: " + customers);
    return customers;
  }
};
```

}

Comment: Pass a callback to your function, and call that instead of returning.

Comment: where do you want to `return` it? a callback function like `do_something(customers);` might be more useful..

Comment: You would use an async callback as well in JavaScript. Haven't you tried it?

Comment: ty for callback as arg. fixed it